# PHP remove duplicate values from multidimensional array but keep last one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

i have this array

```
$items = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => xx [1] => 'update')
[1] => Array ( [0] => bx [1] => 'update')
[2] => Array ( [0] => xx [1] => 'creation')
[3] => Array ( [0] => fs [1] => 'creation')
[4] => Array ( [0] => tx [1] => 'update')
[5] => Array ( [0] => bx [1] => 'creation')
)
```

i'm trying to remove duplicate values based on the first element (xx,bx,ax etc)

if two elements from the same table match, i'd like to keep the last one with higher index,
the result would be like the following

```
$items = Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => xx [1] => 'creation')
    [1] => Array ( [0] => bx [1] => 'creation')
    [2] => Array ( [0] => fs [1] => 'creation')
    [3] => Array ( [0] => tx [1] => 'update')
    )
```

keeping the last one was a bit confusing to me as i'm new to PHP.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Presumably the `ax` entry is supposed to be in the resulting array too?

Comment: yes, i've changed that, its an xx, i forgot to edit that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generic deduplication:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $result[$item[0]] = $item;
}
```

Functional:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function ($acc, $i) {
    return [$i[0] => $i] + $acc;
}, [])
```

Awesome:

```
array_column($array, null, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, i found the solution,
i started bu reversing the array, then executed the following code

```
$taken = array();
$reverse = array_reverse($items, true);
foreach($reverse as $key => $item) {
    if(!in_array($item[0], $taken)) {
        $taken[] = $item[0];
    } else {
        unset($reverse[$key]);
    }
}
```